# Print contents to another file in php

Tags: php

$query="UPDATE `login_detail` set `user_online`='N' where `username`=''";
$query="UPDATE `login_detail` set `user_online`='N' where `username`=''";I am trying to print content from one PHP file to another.When the contents written in file it doesn't like what I want .here is snippet of my code.

```
<?php
$content .='$query='."UPDATE `login_detail` set `user_online`='N' where `username`='".$_SESSION['username']."' \n";
$content .= '$result='.'$mysqli->query($query);'."\n\n";

$file="/var/www/html/inc/test_config.php";
file_put_contents($file, $content, LOCK_EX);
return "<pre>".$content."</pre>";
?>
```

Here is what I get as output in test_config.php file.

$query="UPDATE `login_detail` set `user_online`='N' where `username`=''";

```
$result=$mysqli->query($query);
```

I didn't get value in where `username=`

Comment: start session before writing that query. `session_start();`

Comment: did you use session_start() in your test_config.php ?

Comment: the output you show doesn't match the input string

Comment: @dp No I haven't use it in file

Comment: @NanaPartykar I just want to print same

Comment: use session_start before you use session variable .it will work

Comment: I know nirali. For getting session values, you have to `start_session();`

Answer (score 0):

There was a mismatch in quotes with the original - it would not have produced valid code as it was.
Ensure the session variable is defined also!

```
$content='';
$content .="\$query=\"UPDATE `login_detail` set `user_online`='N' where `username`='".'{$_SESSION["username"]}'."';\"; \n";
$content .= '$result=$mysqli->query( $query );'."\n\n";
file_put_contents('c:/temp/blah.txt',$content );
```

this produces, in the output file, the following:

```
$query="UPDATE `login_detail` set `user_online`='N' where `username`='{$_SESSION["username"]}';"; 
$result=$mysqli->query( $query );
```

Comment: I want out out like.    $query  = "UPDATE `login_detail` set `user_online`='N' where `username`='".$_SESSION['username']."' ";

Comment: printing the query in another file